# How to apply evalf() to an expression from symengine.py?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, symengine

**We couldn't find any `evalf()` in the package `symengine` for python. Does there exist any?**

More detailed explanation of our problem.

We are trying to switch to `symengine` instead of `sympy` because we percept essential speedup. We use symbolic algebra tools to solve problem of optimisation which has applications in combinatorial random structure generation.

After some testing on sympy, we discovered that solving some "innocent-looking" optimisation problems requires intermediate computations in range `1e+24` and beyond (but in the end they finally provide the correct answer). Then I discovered that I misused sympy's function `subs()` because it is less precise than `evalf()` with substitution dictionary.

This issue is descried in the manual of the function subs:

```
If the substitution will be followed by numerical
evaluation, it is better to pass the substitution to
evalf as

>>> (1/x).evalf(subs={x: 3.0}, n=21)
0.333333333333333333333

rather than

>>> (1/x).subs({x: 3.0}).evalf(21)
0.333333333333333314830
```

as the former will ensure that the desired level of precision is
obtained. In fact, substituting e+24 using standard `sympy.subs()` function, or `symengine.subs()` throws an infinity, though e+24 is still in the range of numpy.float64, which I suspect to be a standard type that my machine casts into, when I call built-in `float(...)` function.

We are aware of ["lambdify"](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html), which is a recommended step if you do repetitive substitutions and want high numerical precision, but this will be the next step. We couldn't use the manuals from python interpreter because the code is precompiled, and on the internet it is also difficult to find any. Looking inside the source also didn't help (but maybe I missed something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `evalf` on symengine yet. Here's how the above can be achieved,

```
In [14]: (1/x).subs({x: 3}).n(73, real=True)
Out[14]: 0.333333333333333333333
```

Note that if you do like below, it will do the substitution in precision 53 (15 decimal digits)

```
In [15]: (1/x).subs({x: 3.0}).n(73, real=True)
Out[15]: 0.333333333333333314830
```

You can use subs with `Float(3.0, dps=21)` instead of just `3.0` to do the calculations in higher precision. Below example will work with both symengine and sympy.

```
In [16]: (1/x).subs({x: Float(3.0, dps=21)})
Out[16]: 0.333333333333333333333
```

Note that `.n()` in symengine prefers precision in binary digits instead of decimal digits and `real=True` needs to be given for real domain, otherwise it'll assume complex and give you a complex number with imaginary part `0.` and will be a little slower than `real=True`.

Comment: Hi Isuru! it works assuming that `Float` is from `symengine.Float`. Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: My concern was about long double arithmetics. For example, in sympy, `sp.exp(x).evalf(subs={x:1e+24})`
returns `3.87630247116649e+434294481903251820364876`
however symengine gives infinity ;)
Is there any way to use such large numbers?

Comment: Ah, not yet. The underlying library for arbitrary precision used is MPFR and that library has a maximum exponent size of `2**64-1`, but `434294481903251820364876` is bigger than that and hence the infinity result. There was some work done to integrate another library `arb` which supports arbitrary precision exponent sizes, but it's not done yet.